# After moving javascript in footer slideshow and testimonial doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, wordpress, footer

as you can see [HERE](http://www.pxrfs.com.au/) The slideshow is not displayed since I moved (through wp minify fix plugin) everything in the footer. I gained a lot of scores with pagespeed tests but I have to fix the slider, any help?

Thanks,
Daniele

Comment: include jquery first ??

Comment: > Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the entire answer, but it appears you have removed JQuery from your scripts being loaded. There are quite a few inline scripts in your page header which require it.

EDIT:  One way to re-include it would be to edit your theme's functions.php and add the following code

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);

function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Above code quoted from: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/

Comment: I tried to include jquery but the plugin remove it... any idea How can i add it?

Comment: There are many ways of including jquery, the most important thing in your case is to make sure jquery is included above all the inline scripts which require it. I have edited my answer above with the `wp_enqueue_script` method, if this still produces errors you may need to check the loading order.

Comment: it is still not working, what do you mean by loading order and how can I modify it?

Comment: I mean that in your websites source you should check that the `<script>` tag which loads `jquery.min.js` is above any code in the page which has calls to jQuery.

Comment: Ok i got that, but How can I do that practically? If I add the code the plugin moves it in the footer....

Comment: In that case instead of the above code I would manually edit your themes header.php and manually add the JQuery `<script>` tag at the top of the head. The only issue you may run into with this method is double-loading of JQuery, so you may want to modify the functions.php to also run `wp_deregister_script('jquery');`